# Restrict PHP in subdirectories

Tags: php, subdomain, shared-hosting, wildcard-subdomain

I have registered a wildcard subdomain record for the dir `/.../public_html/hosting/accounts/`. When a user requests a hosting space, I generate a folder in `accounts`. My `index.php` (which is also the 404 ErrorDocument) in `accounts` uses some basic **PHP** code to determine the subdomain and the path. Using display the file using `include({subdomain}/{requested file})`.

Therefore, `demo.example.com/file` would trigger a 404 and the `index.php` will display the file at `example.com/hosting/accounts/demo/file`.

I am, however, concerned that the users would be able to access the files of others via `get_file_contents`, `include`, `exec` and etc.

Is this the correct way to provide hosting on a subdomain? Is there another way to do it?

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? What makes you think that there are standards?

Comment: @Nico Haase For this approach that I'm developing isn't completely robust and I am not sure if there's another way that is more secure and reliable. Perhaps there's something with me and my Google search terms, but I couldn't find any example practices/platforms etc.